# Using delegate func as method parameter error

Tags: c#, func

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Func<Employee, int> getId = (x => x.EmployeeId);
        Func<TextBox, string> getInput = (x => x.Text);
        txtName.Text = GetInput(getInput);
    }


private string GetInput<T>(Func<T, string> getInput)
    {
        string s = getInput(this.txtName.Text);
        return "Hello "+s;
    }
```

At "string s = getInput(this.txtName.Text);" line i am facing the error "Delegate 'System.Func' has some invalid arguments".... what is the problem...
can someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a compile time error because you've declared `Func<T, string> getInput`, but attempt to pass a `string` to it.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx:

> `public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(
>       T arg
>   )`

You've declared `getInput` as being a function which takes a `T` parameter, but you're attempting to pass it a `string`.

The `Func<T, string> getInput` may be conceptually represented as:

```
string getInput(T parameter)
```

I believe you probably intend to do something like this:

```
private string GetInput(Func<TextBox, string> getInput)
{
    return String.Format("Hello {0}", getInput(this.txtName));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried passing textbox as input...but getting same problem.

Comment: Hmm - it can't possibly be the same error, unless there's other code causing it. Your original code would definitely generate a compile time error `Delegate 'System.Func<T,string>' has some invalid arguments`, and my modification would not.

Comment: This is my entire code.

'  public partial class Form1 : Form 
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Func<Employee, int> getId = (x => x.EmployeeId);

            Func<TextBox, string> getInput = (x => x.Text);

            txtName.Text = GetInput(getInput);
        }

        public string GetInput<T>(Func<T, string> getInput)
        {
            return String.Format("Hello {0}", getInput(this.txtName));
        }

    }'

Answer (score 1):

You don't need generics here since your passing a string as an input param and expecting a string as an output param:

```
private string GetInput(Func<string, string> getInput)
{
    string s = getInput(this.txtName.Text);
    return "Hello "+s;
}
```

Comment: I tried as below

private string GetInput(Func<string, string> getInput)
{
    string s = getInput(this.txtName);
    return "Hello "+s;
}

but still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean

```
string s = getInput(this.txtName);
```

instead of `string s = getInput(this.txtName.Text)`, as the latter call does not match the signature of `getInput`, which takes a `TextBox` as an argument.